# Want to Display the telugu content in the android app coming from the http request

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-asynctask

Iam developing small news reader app,I want to display the telugu content coming from the server(http request response).
sample Format of result

status": "ok",
"count": 7,
"count_total": 7,
"pages": 1,
"posts":
[

{

```
"id": 152,
"type": "post",
"slug": "%e0%b0%ac%e0%b0%be%e0%b0%b9%e0%b1%81%e0%b0%ac%e0%b0%b2%e0%b0%bf-%e0%b0%b5%e0%b1%80%e0%b0%a1%e0%b0%bf%e0%b0%af%e0%b1%8b-%e0%b0%9a%e0%b1%82%e0%b0%b6%e0%b0%be%e0%b0%b0%e0%b1%8b-%e0%b0%85%e0%b0%82",
"url": "http://google.com/%e0%b0%ac%e0%b0%be%e0%b0%b9%e0%b1%81%e0%b0%ac%e0%b0%b2%e0%b0%bf-%e0%b0%b5%e0%b1%80%e0%b0%a1%e0%b0%bf%e0%b0%af%e0%b1%8b-%e0%b0%9a%e0%b1%82%e0%b0%b6%e0%b0%be%e0%b0%b0%e0%b1%8b-%e0%b0%85%e0%b0%82/",
"status": "publish",
"title": "బాహుబలి వీడియో చూశారో అంతే..",
"title_plain": "బాహుబలి వీడియో చూశారో అంతే..",
"content": "<p>బాహుబలి సినిమాకు సంబంధించి 12 నిమిషాల వీడియో ఒకటి లీకైందని.. ఆ విషయంలో ఓ వీఎఫ్ఎక్స్ ఎఫెక్టులు చేసే కంపెనీకి చెందిన ఉద్యోగిపై బాహుబలి టీమ్ కేసు పెట్టిందని రెండు మూడు రోజులుగా వార్తలొస్తున్న సంగతి తెలిసిందే. ఐతే ఇలాంటి ఉదంతాలు టాలీవుడ్‌కు కొత్తేమీ కాదు. కొందరు నిర్మాతలు పబ్లిసిటీ కోసం కావాలనే ఇలాంటి వీడియోలు లీక్ చేయడం కూడా అనుభవమే. బాహుబలి వ్యవహారం కూడా ఇలాంటిదేనేమో అన్న సందేహాలు వ్యక్తమయ్యాయి. ఐతే రాజమౌళి టీమ్‌కు అలాంటి ఉద్దేశమేమీ లేదని తెలుస్తోంది. ఎందుకంటే ఆ వీడియోను లీక్ చేసిన వ్యక్తి మీద కేసు పెట్టడంతో టీమ్ బాహుబలి ఆగట్లేదు. ఈ వీడియోను చూసిన, షేర్ చేసిన వాళ్ల మీద కూడా చర్యలు తీసుకుంటోంది.</p>\n<p><img class=\"aligncenter wp-image-153 size-medium\" src=\"http://google.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Bahubali-first-look-300x161.jpg\" alt=\"Bahubali\" width=\"300\" height=\"161\" /></p>\n<p>ఇప్పటికే ఫేస్ బుక్, ట్విట్టర్ ద్వారా ఈ వీడియోని స్ప్రెడ్ చేసిన వారిపైనా కేసులు ఫైల్ చేసారు. తెలంగాణ, ఆంధ్రప్రదేశ్ పోలీస్ డిపార్ట్మెంట్స్, సైబర్ క్రైమ్ డివిజన్ వారు ఫేస్ బుక్, ట్విట్టర్ లలో షేర్ చేస్తున్న వారిని ట్రాక్ చేసి వారిని పట్టుకుంటున్నారు. కొందరిని అరెస్ట్ కూడా చేశారు. టాలీవుడ్ యాంటీ పైరసీ టీం కూడా ఈ విషయాన్ని సీరియస్‌గా తీసుకోవడంతో వీడియోను స్ప్రెడ్ చేసిన వారు అడ్డంగా ఇరుక్కుపోయినట్లే. ఎవరో వీడియో పెట్టారు కదా.. షేర్ చేస్తే పోయేదేముందని క్లిక్ చేశారంటే అంతే సంగతులు. కాబట్టి బాహుబలి వీడియో కనిపిస్తే దూరంగా ఉండడం బెటర్.</p>\n",
"excerpt": "<p>బాహుబలి సినిమాకు సంబంధించి 12 నిమిషాల వీడియో ఒకటి లీకైందని.. ఆ విషయంలో ఓ వీఎఫ్ఎక్స్ ఎఫెక్టులు చేసే కంపెనీకి..</p>\n",
"date": "2015-01-27 23:31:58",
"modified": "2015-01-27 23:37:11"
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kitkat onwards Android has support for telugu font.

If your targeted device do not have telugu font then place that `telugu.ttf`  in your application's `assest` folder.

```
   TextView text_view = new TextView(this);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "telugu.ttf");
    text_view.setTypeface(font);
    text_view.setText("బాహుబలి వీడియో చూశారో అంతే..");
```

You can check ttf file name from your android system

```
adb shell
cd system/fonts
ls
```

Comment: I want the response converting from input stream to corresponding language string.here you are using static string to set for the textview. but i want to set the data of httprequest reponse.I tried for converting input stream to json. but the telugu content converted to unicode like \u0c2c\u0c3e\u0c39\u0c41\u0c2c\u0c32\u0c3f. so please tel me how to convert the result to string(in telugu language).

Comment: @honey you can store your telugu unicione in any String variable and give that variable in  text_view.setText(StringVariableName);